# Can't send mail from page using django , SMTPAuthenticationError

Tags: python, django, smtp

I just started using python and django , I'm trying to send an email from a page directy to my email but the moment i send it the page gives me this error "SMTPAuthenticationError" , i already Less secure apps and disable captcha code

this is how i configured my setting

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'mymail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

and this is the function i coded in the views file

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from TatooPage.models import UserRequest

    def email_request(request):
    name = request.POST['name']
    email = request.POST['email']
    message = request.POST['message']

    send_mail(
        'Message from' + name,
        message,
        email,
        ['mymail@gmail.com'],
    )

    user_details = UserRequest(
        name=name,
        email=email,
        message=message
    )

    user_details.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact-us/')
```

Don't know if there would be anything else i should add .

Answer (score 0):

Nvm I found the problem just had to add this line in the setting , leaving this here in case someone else has the same problem :P

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```